# VBA copies string and pastes scientific notation

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a problem with the below code.
The code is supposed to copy long strings. 
The source file has this  content as string. It is about 50 characters long. There are digits and letter mixed.

The problem is that for some of the pasted ranges they are in scientific notation which cannot be looked up by the other functions.

Here is the relevant section of the code

```
For i = 1 To Columns.Count        
    If Left(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).Value, 4) = "1068" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).End(xlUp), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).End(xlDown)).Copy _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)                   
    End If
Next i
```

Is there a way to paste only values for such a range?
I've tried with method "paste values" but got VBA error message

Comment: Assuming you have multiple rows of data, this code seems strange to me because you start checking ROW 7, column A for 1068, then if found, you select every cell from the top to the bottom and paste at the bottom of column A? Then you repeat for the rest of the columns?

Comment: yes it is strange. But it the report I copy it from is so irregular that it starts once from 3rd row the other time from 5th. so the 7th is the closest and sure to meet data at the same time

Comment: If the report was regular like starting from top row I would surely use 2nd row and down

Comment: Unfortunately, your description of the issue doesn't provide anyone with the specifics of what you want to do. Copying 'long strings' can be different than copying cells. Please try giving an example where you have 5 rows, and the 3rd and 5th rows have your "1068" in column A and C. What EXACTLY do you want to copy for the first one, and EXACTLY where do you want to paste it. Then explain the same for Col. C.

Comment: How would you like me to show it?  Additional info is that the source file is a csv file converted to xlsx by other macro

Comment: Is there a different way too "transfer" string values from one workbook to the other

Comment: Did one of the three answers provided by others solve your problem? If so, great. If not, I'm still waiting to hear your description of what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately none of the suggestions resolved my problem. I put what I am trying to do. I open around 13 files. They are .csv converted into .xlsx. I select specific columns by defined criteria in the macro code and copy entire non-empty column (as a range) to macro file. I copy ranges one below the previous. All the columns copied end at the same row in the result file. I found for two files that some (not all) values are pasted as scientific notation even if I format the source range and the

Comment: output range as text, as suggested below by a colleague. Is there a way to copy that as a real string or whatever that shows all the characters like this example: 10303389607BFTaavdj020170206Z009QWAR1
instead of 1.01E+41
Many thanks

Comment: I have no problem finding, copying and pasting. Have used scientific and general. Also pasted values. (1) How about showing us the actual content of one column you are copying when it fails. (2) what is the format of each of the cells in your copy range when it fails ?   (3) Please agree that we are ONLY looking at the sample code you provided. We don't care about csv files, etc,

Comment: Okay, the problem is now different. Copying pasting is OK. The issue is that the original source file has got scientific notation on several items. The question is how to programmatically convert multiple files into a proper format so that all data in them are as strings not scientific notation? Thank you for your commitment

Comment: I have prepared the source file I would like to show you. However, I have no idea how to upload anything here. I have restricted google drive and probably other stuff like that too. Is there any other way to share it? Email to you Guys?

Comment: Maybe this: is there any way to view scientific notation as text in csv file?  Importing this through data, import from text does not show this correctly.  The only way to view the real value I found was to open csv file in notepad and see it there. Converting programmatically does not work with formula =text() neither nor by copy paste from notepad.  This is really crazy stuff. Apologies.

Comment: You need to open a new question as this one has changed greatly from the original topic.

Comment: Thank all of you for the input. Fortunately I managed to resolve it myself

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).End(xlUp), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).End(xlDown)).Copy _
    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Do this instead:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range( _
          ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).End(xlUp), _
          ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).End(xlDown) _
                              ).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues  

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Alternatively, I suggest something along the lines of to make the code clearer:

```
Dim rngCopyFrom as Range
Dim rngCopyTo as Range
Set rngCopyFrom = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range( _
              ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).End(xlUp), _
              ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).End(xlDown) _
                              )
Set rngCopyTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
rngCopyFrom.Copy
rngCopyTo.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of the cells.

You can correct it by using:

```
.NumberFormat = "##0_)"
```

Here is a sample of how to manage the format:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).NumberFormat = "##0_)"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).End(xlUp), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, i).End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "##0_)"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "##0_)"
```

Once the formatting is changed, the scientific notation should not display.

Comment: Thank you I will get back to you once I try it out

Comment: Hi, sorry it does not work. It should paste "10303389607BFTaavdj020170206Z009QWAR1" but it pasted "1.01E+41"

Comment: I see where the code I had would only be intended for numbers with no text. However, the condition that you are having does not make sense. Check the reference of the cell. You may have it off by a column. If you are still having issues, feel free to post a workbook with this row of data on it along with the segment of code with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To CONVERT the numerical strings to numerical values :

```
t = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(7, I).End(xlUp), _
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, I).End(xlDown) _
).Value
Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Cells(1).Resize(UBound(t))
dest.NumberFormat = ""
dest.FormulaLocal = t
```